# create 2D array from wavelets coefficients using python

Tags: python, arrays, signal-processing, interpolation, wavelet

I need to create 2D array similar to figure below using coefficients of details of a wavelet transform.
I am trying for more than 2 weeks to find how I can do it.

[image]

This plot represents coefficients of details of a wavelet transformation at different levels (1, 2, 3,4 and 5).The coefficients of details (cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1=coeffs) are a 1D array and each has different size. I want to create 2D array similar to the image using the wavelet coefficients how I can do that?

```
coeffs = wavedec(data, 'sym5', level=5)
    cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1=coeffs    
    for i, ci in enumerate(coeffs):
        plt.imshow(ci.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, 2000, i + 0.5, i + 1.5], cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.ylim(0.5, len(coeffs) + 0.5) 
    plt.yticks(range(1, len(coeffs) + 1), ['cA5', 'cD5', 'cD4', 'cD3', 'cD2', 'cD1'])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the 1D arrays not of the same size, how do you should fill the empty spaces?

Comment: @David S I don't know how I fill the empty spaces may be by scaling or interpolation I don't know if that right. I just want to convert the image to 2D array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is easier than you might have thought.

Simply take out `plt.show()` from your `for` loop:

```
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=np.random.rand(4000)
coeffs = pywt.wavedec(data, 'sym5', level=5)
cA5,cD5,cD4,cD3,cD2,cD1=coeffs    
for i, ci in enumerate(coeffs):
    plt.imshow(ci.reshape(1, -1), extent=[0, 2000, i + 0.5, i + 1.5],     cmap='inferno', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.ylim(0.5, len(coeffs) + 0.5) 
    plt.yticks(range(1, len(coeffs) + 1), ['cA5', 'cD5', 'cD4', 'cD3', 'cD2', 'cD1'])
plt.show()
```

This will allow you to update your figure:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

If you leave `plt.show()` in the loop, it will provide individual plots for each coefficient such as the one below:

[image]

Citing this [introduction to matplotlib](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.00-introduction-to-matplotlib.html):

> One thing to be aware of: the plt.show() command should be used only
>   once per Python session, and is most often seen at the very end of the
>   script. Multiple show() commands can lead to unpredictable
>   backend-dependent behavior, and should mostly be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't understand , Is my code doesn't update the figure in each C ??